# how to use custom helper in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, frameworks

How to use custom helper in codeigniter? This function is not work inside of codeigniter but outside of codeigniter work properly

```
function next_element($array)
{

    static $index_position = 0;

    if ($index_position==count($array)) 
    {
        $index_position = 0; 
    }

    return $array[$index_position++];

}

$week = ['Saturday', 'Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday' ];

echo next_element($week);   // return Saturday
echo next_element($week);   // return Sunday
echo next_element($week);   // return Monday
```

this *helper function* is not work inside of **codeigniter**

Comment: Add some more details about this code.

Comment: This function takes an array as a parameter.
Returns the value from the array by each call.
When the value ends, it returns to the first value.
tthis cycle continues run by every call.

Comment: Outside of Codeigniter means in your Controllers and views ?

Comment: it means, when I testing in any PHP server. like Xampp, https://paiza.io/projects/qXBXYxVONAy317-usT559Q

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already have this function within a custom helper file in `application/helpers`, but just in case you don't, I'll walk you through it

First, create the helper file within the `application/helpers` directory. Name the file to you heart's desire, but suffix it with `_helper` (e.g., `yourhelperfile_helper.php`)

Second, add any and all helper functions you need in this way:

```
function someFunction()
{
  // your code goes here
}

function someOtherFunction()
{
  // other code goes here
}
```

Then, make sure your controller is actually loading the helper before you need to make use of it. You can do that in the controller's constructor if you think you'll need it on multiple methods within the controller. You could also autoload it so it's available across all of your controllers, or you could just load it in the specific places where you'll need to use some of those helper functions.
In any case, load the helper with `$this->load->helper('helpername');` without the `_helper` suffix. That is to say, if the helper file is called `mysuperhelperfile_helper.php` load it with `$this->load->helper('mysuperhelperfile');`

Finally, when you need to use a function/method from the helper, just use it like a regular function. In my example above, if the method you need is `someFunction` you can just use `someFunction($params);` within the controller or even within a view which is loaded by the controller.

Comment: Need to see some more code and specific error messages you're getting. It's hard to debug in the blind